# TileMill Exports Failing

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, tilemill, mapbox

I'm having trouble exporting my map in TileMill (v0.10.1). I'm using OSM Bright with a PostGIS database connection to import OpenStreetMap data. When exporting an SVG or PDF through the user interface in TileMill, the export fails more often than not with a SIGABRT error. The console shows the following error:

```
[tilemill] [tilemill-ui] Rendering file
[tilemill] [tilemill-ui] libc++abi.dylib: terminating
[tilemill] Export process failed with signal 'SIGABRT'
```

I then tried exporting through the command line by running `./index.js export OSMBright ~/Documents/MapBox/export/cityhall2.svg --format=svg --width=2000 --height=2300 --bbox="-79.8786965, 43.2604005, -79.8702965, 43.2516005"`, with a nearly identical error.

It usually exports a blank file, although once in a while it does export nearly what I want (with zoom levels and symbology slightly off, but still usable).

Has anyone had this problem before? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is (every time I exported SVG it proceeded without errors), but you can try making XML out of CartoCSS with `carto` and then rendering it into an image with [Nik4](https://github.com/Zverik/Nik4).